# Custom package service provider cannot be found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm trying to develop a custom package using "workbench". It's a simple package that will create a repository to consume a different API we have. I plan on injecting this repository into my controllers of my application. Anyway, I created the package using "workbench". This creates the service provider. The Laravel docs say to add the service provider to my "providers" array in app.config. I've done this, but when I run `composer update`, I get an error saying that the class is not found, specifically: `PHP Fatal error: Class 'MyVendor\MyPackage\ServiceProvider not found in /.. .. .. ../laravel/vendor/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php`. I thought I followed the docs correctly, what am I missing?

Comment: Did you run that command within the packages directory?

Comment: I ran `composer install` in the packages directory and it works now. Thanks. The tutorials I was looking at didn't mention that. I guess I just expected my normal application's `composer update` to also handle the workbench stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply running `composer install` inside the workbench directory resolves this issue.